# Split list into 3 part dictionary Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a txt file with emails and ID's in the format of simon@test.com:ID. I am reading the file and removing lines that contain unwanted email domains and adding the rest to a list. I am trying to turn that list into a dictionary so I can easily access items using the username, domain, ID (username@domain:ID) but I'm struggling to split them into 3 sections. I managed to split between the @ using item.split but it can only use 1 separator (@ or :) not both.
Please correct me if I'm wrong but I'm assuming that a dictionary is the best way to access this data down the track rather than a nested list.

```
remove_emails = ['aol', 'yahoo'] #remove these emails from list

email_list = []
with open(r"C:\Python Projects\file.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        if not any(remove_emails in line for remove_emails in remove_emails):
            line = line.strip() #remove line if it contains unwanted emails
            email_list.append(line)

dict_list = [{}]
dict_list = dict(item.split('@') for item in email_list if item) #split line into sections (username, domain, ID)
```

Comment: can you tell what final output do you want for the dict_list?, ie can you give a mock example of how it should look?

Comment: And although `for remove_emails in remove_emails` will work, you shouldn't give them the same name, it's generally considered confusing.

Comment: There are a number of questions here. 1) optimal data structure, 2) chained splitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to do something like this (?):

```py
remove_emails = ['aol', 'yahoo'] #remove these emails from list

email_list = []
with open(r"C:\Python Projects\file.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        if not any(remove_emails in line for remove_emails in remove_emails):
            line = line.strip() #remove line if it contains unwanted emails
            email_list.append(line)

dict_list = []
for item in email_list:
  # Do a first split
  parts = item.split('@')
  username = parts[0]
  # Do a second split
  remaining_parts = parts[1].split(':')
  domain = remaining_parts[0]
  id = remaining_parts[1]
  dict_list.append({"id": id, "username": username, "domain": domain})
```

This example can obviously still throw errors if the separators (@, :) are not present but you can polish that. I think you were trying to fix everything a bit too much with one liners. And it's probably possible with a horrendously long one-liner, but really, there's no need! :) Just loop over your items, parse your data and make a dictionary in each iteration that you append to your `dict_list`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and advise. That is what I'm trying to do but the only problem is how do I get the domain, for example test.com, if username is [0] and id is [1]? So the part between username and ID? Example: username[0] domain[1] id[2]

Comment: The domain is in `remaining_parts[0]` First we split `"A@B:C"` into `parts = ["A", "B:C"]` and then we split `parts[1]` into `remaining_parts = ["B", "C"]`. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what is your key would determine if a dictionary is the right structure for you. You said you wanted to access items using the username, domain, ID, but the true power of a dictionary is finding data based on the key. The key in this scenario seems to be ID. If that's the case, here's a way to created a nested dictionary:

```
import re

remove_emails = ['aol', 'yahoo'] #remove these emails from list

email_list = []
with open(r"test_email.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        if not any(remove_emails in line for remove_emails in remove_emails):
            line = line.strip() #remove line if it contains unwanted emails
            email_list.append(line)

def domain(email):
    try:
        return re.search('@(.*):', email).group(1)
    except:
        return ""


email_dict = {email.split(":")[-1]: {"user": email.split("@")[0], "domain":domain(email)} for email in email_list}
```

Input:

```
kevin@gmail.com:123
titan@yahoo.com:124
hero@meme.com:125
```

Output:

```
{'123': {'user': 'kevin', 'domain': 'gmail.com'},
 '125': {'user': 'hero', 'domain': 'meme.com'}}
```